# Cannot resolve symbol 'ButterKnife'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, butterknife

i am trying to use butterknife . but i got error "**Cannot resolve symbol '**ButterKnife**'" .
i have tried to import butterknife.ButterKnife manually but i got the same error 
and i have modified gradle and added those lines : 
at project level ...

```
dependencies {
              classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
             }
```

at the module level ...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

dependencies { 

   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
   apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1' 

}
```

what shall i do ? 
thanks in advance .
here is a screenshot of my code where i got the error 
[link for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqGsW.png)

Comment: Can you check now...

Comment: Try Clean and Rebuild the project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion XX
    buildToolsVersion "XX.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion xx
        targetSdkVersion xx
        versionCode x
        versionName "x.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'

    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: the issue is here , i replaced :
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
by 
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
and it's work

Answer (score 1):

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
```

Comment: it's give me another error cannot resolve 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

Comment: and i think i haven't to do this due to it's an old version , right !

Comment: the error appears in the screenshot attached with the question

Comment: at project level 
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0' }

at module level
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 

dependencies { 
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [official document here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife).
In short your dependencies looks like below:

```
dependencies {
  // ... other dependencies here
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying ,
i do checked the official document , and i have set my dependencies like this in at first but i was got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.5.1'
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tanamo.tutorial"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
 annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```